# AUTOCOMPLETE MUI not accepting values entered in the textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

i want the autocomplete to accept the value entered in the textfield even if it isn't present the dropdown.

my autocomplete component :

```
<Autocomplete
  disabled={row.group_mapping_id && !('editClicked' in row)}
  freeSolo
  value={row.client_id} 
  onChange={(event, newValue) => props.onChangeTableInput('client_id', index, newValue, row)}
  selectOnFocus
  clearOnBlur
  handleHomeEndKeys
  options={props.clientIds}
  renderOption={(props, option) => <li {...props}>{option.client_id}</li>}
  autoHighlight
  style={{width: '110px'}}
  disableClearable
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} 
  variant='outlined'
  inputProps={{
    ...params.inputProps,
    autoComplete: "disabled",
    type: 'search'
  }} />}
/>
```

clientIds array :

[{client_id : 'abcd'}, {client_id : 'abrd'}] and so on..

onChangeTableInput function :

```
const onChangeTableInput = (keyName, index, keyValue, rowData) => {
    let temp_array = [...props.groupTableData];
    let temp_value = keyValue
    if(keyName === 'client_id'){
      temp_array[index][keyName] = temp_value.client_id;   
    }else if(keyName === 'client_name'){
      temp_array[index][keyName] = temp_value.client_name;
    }else{
      temp_array[index][keyName] = temp_value;
    }
    if (rowData && !rowData.group_mapping_id) {
      temp_array[index]['operation'] = 'N';
    }
    props.setGroupTableData(temp_array);
  }
```

i want the component to accept and display the typed option even if doesn't exist in the dropdown, right now if i don't type an existing option it doesn't display or read the value too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Autocomplete
   {...otherProps}
   defaultValue={{ client_id: row.client_id }}
   getOptionLabel={option => option.client_id}
/>
```

And no need to `renderOption={(props, option) => <li {...props}>{option.client_id}</li>}`